# How to design the database for a chat service that keeps the history

Tags: database-design, chat

I've seen multiple apps that have a chat system, where you can delete the chat from your device, but it will stay stored on the server (for example, when the police require a copy due to illegal activities).

Similarly, if you logout and log back in it will recover the chats that you didn't delete.

Does a service like this still use MySQL tables? And what would the structure of these tables look like to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Larger chat services may only use SQL for recent data (current day or last X messages). The rest of the data is being archived.

Archives, again, may have different levels: from advanced NoSQL storages on spinning disks (can be read/searched on demand, you just have to wait a little) to compressed plain-text content written on a tape in some underground facility. In the latter case, it takes minutes to load the tape into reader alone, yet it's enough for police purposes and it can be stored there for decades.